# Howto generate TrueLicence in Python

Tags: java, python, cryptography, pycrypto

We have a licencing server which generates keys using the Java [TrueLicense](https://truelicense.dev.java.net/) library. I would like to move that code to a Python using the same algorithm so that the new keys will be equivalent with keys generated with the Java code. Perhaps it is possible to use PyCrypto for this. Does anyone know if this can be done without too much effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- make an own implentation of TrueLicense in Python
- write a Java application that interacts with your Python program
- write your Python app or parts of it in [Jython](http://jython.org/) and use the lib directly

Answer (score 2):

This is late, but for anyone else coming here with similar problems:

I have taken the time to read through the TrueLicense source and reimplement most of it in Ruby. Maybe that can help you reimplement it in Python if you wish:

https://github.com/einarmagnus/truby_license

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [jpype](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpype/)

> JPype is an effort to allow python
>   programs full access to java class
>   libraries. This is achieved not
>   through re-implementing Python, as
>   Jython/JPython has done, but rather
>   through interfacing at the native
>   level in both Virtual Machines.